# How to hide content of the collection view if I clicked a search bar to type something in there?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working on an app for iOS in swift 3 and here is my question. How would I implement a feature that when I choose a search bar to type something inside, all the pictures under it, would hide (aka Instagram style)?

For example in Instagram, when you click a search bar all pictures would hide if search bar is active. Here is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

Function where I am calling my search bar:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
            let headerView:UICollectionReusableView =  collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SearchFoodHeader", for: indexPath)

            return headerView
        }

        return UICollectionReusableView()

    }
```

Could somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When your search bar becomes active (e.g. `becomeFirstResponder`), you can change your collection view's [`numberOfItemsInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618058-collectionview) method to return zero (you might also need to `reloadData` on your collection view as well).

And in a practical sense, what you really need to do is have your collection view data source pull from an array of items that match whatever criteria your want your user to be able to search from.  When the user first touches the search bar, the array should be empty (and therefore the number of visible items in your collection view would be zero as well).

[Here is a tutorial that might help you out somewhat](https://maniacdev.com/2015/01/example-how-to-integrate-uicollectionview-with-uisearchbar).

Comment: Actually, I am calling my search bar programmatically, I will add a function to the question that you can see it. Btw, could you please look at it and advice something because I am a beginner in programming?

Comment: Same concept should still applies.  If you are using that "`SearchFoodHeader`" header, you should still have an array with matches for your search term that `numberOfItemsInSection:` draws from (so a blank empty string in the search field when it first appears should be result in no cells being displayed).

Comment: Okay, but the thing is, I do not really understand how to refer to searchBar right now. I did not drag and drop it to my class. Usually, it comes as an `outlet`, but I do not have that, also when I try to drag and drop it, it gives me an error which says that you cannot connect it twice. Means it's connected somehow already via that function. My array always will be full because I do fetching images from a database and there will be something for sure. I was thinking about, to check if searchBarTextDidBeginEditing is true then just hide cells. So what can I use as a variable for my searchBar?

Comment: for my own searchBars, I usually don't include them in a headerview but instead I'll make the searchBar be part of the view controller that owns the collection (or table) view, usually positioned at the top (and above) the collection view.  Do you need to have this search bar in the collection view's header view like this?

Comment: Somehow, Xcode doesn't allow me to do it without Reusable View, which causes me to use header view.